# Why do I get this compilation warning in a kernel module with ioctl?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

When defining `t_ioctl` like this, I get no warning:

```
long t_ioctl(struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long input){
```

When defining `t_ioctl` like this:

```
static long t_ioctl(struct file *filep, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long input){
```

I get the warning:

```
warning: 't_ioctl' defined but not used
```

but when it is up to `t_read` or `t_write` the static and non static function declaration doesn't cause the warning. e.g:

```
static ssize_t t_read(struct file *filp, char __user * buf, size_t count, loff_t * f_pos);
```

Why do I get the warning in one case and not the other?

Comment: The warning is clear. Static means it needs to be used inside the file and will not be available externally.

Comment: if it is true why it doesn't hold for these :static ssize_t t_read(struct file *filp, char __user * buf, size_t count, loff_t * f_pos)

Comment: Because `t-read` is actually used?

Comment: it is not used with in the module....

Comment: When you say 'it [`t_read()`] is not used within the module', do you mean that the only two occurrences of `t_read` outside of comments are in the static declaration and the static definition (or the only occurrence is the static definition)?  Or is it used in an initializer somewhere — unlike `t_ioctl`?  Have you looked at the output of the C preprocessor?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how do yo look at the output of c preprocessor?the two occurrences are  only at the deceleration.

Comment: Looking at C preprocessor output varies by compiler (but they all support the option).  With `gcc`, use `-E` (with `make`, I often use `make CC="gcc -E"` to get the other compilation flags too).  There will be a lot of output – capture it for cleanup and scrutiny.  If the only places where `t_ioctl` is mentioned are in its definition/declaration, but `t_read` is also mentioned in an initializer (as in Lance's answer), then that is why you get the warnings on `t_ioctl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you have a definition like this in the same file:

```
static struct file_operations fileops = {
    .read     = t_read,
    .write    = t_write,
    /* etc. ... */
};
```

And you're missing

```
.compat_ioctl = t_ioctl, /* or .ioctl/.unlocked_ioctl, depending on version etc. */
```

Comment: It should also be noted, that the ioctl fops field not being set implies that ioctl calls on the devices fd will result in a EINVAL error.

Comment: why do I get an this error: unknown field 'ioctl' specified in initializer, when I assign like this: .ioctl = t_ioctl or .compat_ioctl = t_ioctl...but .unlocked_ioctl=t_ioctl works fine????

Comment: In more recent kernels (somewhere between 2.6.28 and 3.2), the "ioctl" memmber of the file_operations structure was removed. I believe this was part of a set of changes aimed at removing the BKL.